# Scrolling a tableview inside a popover creates an artifact

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller, popover

If you look at the button/label titled "Address" you'll notice a little speck of white in the corner. This speck of white only occurs when the user starts scrolling the tableView, which is located underneath the searchbar.

I can only guess that the modal border kills all transparencies while scrolling.

[image]
[image]

Comment: if you've defined your user interface in a XIB, could you *shrink* the height of the table view so that the top edge of the table view only touches the bottom edge of the search bar?

Comment: I've seen this in my interfaces as well. Not sure how to fix it, though.

Comment: I've tried moving all the views downwards and applies certain properties to all the views, I speak about this more in depth with my conversation with David Below, and this is what I saw when I dragged the table http://i.imgur.com/4sLkP.png Perlexing

Answer (score 1):

This is an iOS issue with regards to scroll view and is seen in many places - no solution other than you reducing or creating some offset for the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

this artifact could be caused by a variety of different things. The first things I would check when seeing these things is that all of the UIViews (and there subviews) that overlap this area

A. Have a background color with an alpha value of 0

B. Have "Cear Graphics Context" turned off in Interface Builder (or corresponding flag in code)

Comment: I'm unclear about making the background color with an alpha of zero. Do you mean settings the alpha of the view to zero? I don't think that's what you mean because that'd make the view completely transparent.

Comment: - (void)makeBackgroundWhite:(UIView *)view {
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
    for(UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        if(subview.subviews.count) {
            [self makeBackgroundWhite:subview];
        }
    }
}

Comment: I made a recursive function that set all the uiviews in the controller to [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f]; but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: I see in your makeBackgroundWhite function that you left the alpha at 1.0. It should be at 0 so it will be transparent: You do not want a background color (but obviously you don't want to set the UIView.Alpha to 0 or everything will be invisible.)

Comment: - (void)makeBackgroundWhite:(UIView *)view { 
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:0.0f]; 
    view.opaque = NO;
    view.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO;
    for(UIView *subview in view.subviews) { 
        if(subview.subviews.count) { 
            [self makeBackgroundWhite:subview]; 
        } 
    } 
}

Comment: I went through and made everything opaque on top of clearing out the context and changing the alpha to 0.0f. I shifted all the views down by some arbitrary number to limit the amount of views in the area near the corners. And while I was dragging I saw this http://i.imgur.com/4sLkP.png Before the code was added the area above the buttons was white but now it's transparent but unfortunately the corners re appear while dragging the table.